# Spring mvc selecting list items using check box

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I would like to select some or all of the list elements out of populated list and fetch those at the controller which is giving NulllPointerException when fetching at .POST controller, details are..

```
Model Class
```

```
public class Invoice {
            private int number;
            private String name;
            private String description;
            private Date date;
            private Double amount;
            private Double due;

                   .........setters and  getters ....
               }
```

Form Backing Object:

```
public class Invoices {

                    List<Invoice> invoiceList;
                    ......... setter and getter  .....
                  }
```

Controller to show form is

```
Controller is:                             
    @RequestMapping(value = "/viewForm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String viewInvoice(Model model) {
    List<Invoice>invoiceList = new CreateInvoiceItem().createItem();
    Invoices invoices = new Invoices();
    invoices.setInvoiceList(invoiceList);
    model.addAttribute("invoices",invoices);
    return "invoicelist";
}
```

I have used a class to generate some data dynamically using

```
 CreateInvoiceItem().createItem();
```

to show the form in jsp the code is:

```
    <form:form action="viewSelectedList" path="invoices" 
      method="POST" commandName="invoices"> 
     <table> <tr> <td>Action</td> <td>#</td> <td>Name</td>
              <td>Description</td> <td>Date</td>
                  <td>Amount</td>  <td>Due</td> </tr>
 <jstl:forEach var="list" items="${invoices.invoiceList}" >
  <tr>  <td><input type="checkbox" value="${list.number}"  
                 id="${list.number}" name="${list.number}"/></td>
    <td><jstl:out value="${list.number}"/> </td>
    <td><jstl:out value="${list.name}"/> </td>
    <td><jstl:out value="${list.description}"/> </td>
    <td><fmt:formatDate pattern="dd-MM-yyyy"    
                     value="${list.date}" /></td> 
    <td><jstl:out value="${list.amount}"/> </td>
    <td><jstl:out value="${list.due}"/> </td>
 </tr>
</jstl:forEach> 
<tr><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></td>
</tr>
</table>
    </form:form>
```

Upto here it is working fine the output is :
[image]

But when clicking on the submit button the .POST controller is showing the NullPopinterException:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/viewSelectedList", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String showList(Model model, Invoices invoices,
BindingResult result) {
List<Invoice> selectedList = invoices.invoiceList;
model.addAttribute(invoices);
return "selectedList";
}
```

The selected list is not available in POST controller. I have seen many examples but I could not understand where I am going wrong.

Comment: So, you're adding a `invoices` attribute that will be submitted in the post, but that's an empty object and no data is being added into it for the post. And that's why your getting a Null Pointer

Comment: If I am loading the list items to invoices like invoices.set(invoiceList) then by default all the checkboxes are getting checked. that's why I have sent separate with in the commandName the list of the checkboxes to be loaded to invoices when chcking the checkbox...

Comment: ok, I have added the list to the invoices which is commandName invoices.setInvoiceList(invoiceList); still I am not getting the selected list from the jsp to controller

Comment: @raja Don't post a code with images, edit your question and replace them with text.

Comment: I have added the jsp page code, I think that It will be better

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to get selected or checked "invoicelist" row's in controller after submitting the form. If your "invoicelist" are being populated from a database. If that's the case, your "list.number" is equivalent to "id".

> What you will need to do is :

- You need `<input type="checkbox" name="ids[]" id="ids[]" value="${list.numbers}" />` instead of : `<input type="checkbox" value="${list.number}" id="${list.number}" name="${list.number}"/>`
- Send only "number" to "showList" controller.
- Then get each "invoiceList" row by using "number.list" inside a for loop and modify your controller like below example.

> Modified controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/viewSelectedList", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String showList(
Model model, 
Invoices invoices,
BindingResult result,
@RequestParam(value="ids[]") Long ids[]; // added paramater
) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Invoice>> selectedInvoice= new ArrayList<ArrayList<Invoice>>();
    for (Long id : ids){
        List<Invoice> inv = invoiceServiceImpl.findPost(id); // This method should get list of invoices as per row
        selectedInvoice.add((ArrayList<Invoice>) inv);
    }
}
```

Now you will have the selected or checked "invoiceList" do whatever you want to do with it.

> If you do not want to query "invoice" row from a database each time inside a "showlist" method.

just write a search mechanism for search by id in already generated "invoicelist" and get each row inside for loop to get a selected or checked "invoices".

> Note : you will need to modify your form and write a little bit of
>   javascript for this modified codes to work efficiently.

For example if you will not check any of the checkbox you will get error. so you need to validate whether your checkbox is empty or not with javascript.

You can add functionality to select all check box at once by using master checkbox where you have used column name "action" in table. this requires extra javascript.

Hope this would help.